# MySQL Script with rollback on error

Tags: mysql, transactions

I am trying to create a transaction in MySql which will roll back when an exception occurs during the transaction. Similar using the following in a stored procedure.

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK;
```

Can this be done without writing a stored procedure? For example the following snippet should roll back the first insert because the second insert would fail.

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO mytable VALUE 'foo1',2,'foo3','foo4'
INSERT INTO mytable VALUE 'foo1','foo2','foo3','foo4'
COMMIT
```

Comment: Are you using PHP? As this can achieve at programming side.

Comment: No PHP just SQL. I can accomplish in Java but requirements request just SQL script.

Comment: Why didn't you use a stored procedure?

Comment: Stored procedure option is not currently available to me.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly you want to run a SQL script containing, for example inserts, in a single transaction that will rollback if any of the inserts fail. Is right?

I'm not 100% on this, but I'm pretty sure you'd need to do this as a stored procedure or programatically in, say, Java.

Comment: Yes this is what I want to do and is the conclusion I cam to from searching the internet, but I find it difficult to believe the option is not available to em from an SQL Script.